# This expression has type 'a list but an expression was expected of type 'b * 'c

Tags: ocaml

I don't understand why I'm getting this error message, and I'd be glad to be enlightened about it

```
let write c v d =
  let rec new_dict=function 
    | []->(k, v)
    | (key,value)::q-> if key=k
                        then new_dict (q) 
                        else (key,value)::new_dict (q)
  in new_dict (d) ;;
```

Here i aimed to create a new dictionary in which the key 'c' would get a new value, or adding that key if it wasn't in the dictionary in the first place.

Sorry if my error is kind of obvious, I'm new to OcamL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider `new_dict` only, with some formatting cleanup.

```
let rec new_dict = 
  function 
  | [] -> (k, v)
  | (key, value)::q -> 
    if key = k then 
      new_dict q
    else 
      (key, value) :: new_dict q
```

In the event the list is empty, it returns a tuple.  Otherwise it returns a list. Note the `::` list constructor.

Perhaps you meant:

```
let rec new_dict = 
  function 
  | [] -> [(k, v)]
  | (key, value)::q -> 
    if key = k then 
      new_dict q
    else 
      (key, value) :: new_dict q
```